# Continuous Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X$ follows a continuous uniform distribution from `1 to 5`. Determine the conditional probability

$P(X > 2.5 | X \le 4)$

I am not sure I know how to do it. So I need your help. I dont expect answers from you guys, but little help understanding the concept will be helpful.

Comment: Use the usual definitions for conditional probabilities. You can look them up at wikipedia.

Comment: @Karl Can you tell me how to approach? I Know the formula of conditional probability, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, but the basics you have to learn yourself.

Comment: If you know that $X \leq 4$ then you are sure you have a value between 1 and 4 and all values are equally likely.

Comment: Now you know that you have $X > 2.5$, what % of values that you can still draw are bigger than 2.5? You can just look at the pure % of values because all outcomes are equally likely. Just look at how big the interval of values is of $> 2.5$ compared to the whole interval.